# Crawl Wikipedia using ASP.NET HttpWebRequest

Tags: httpwebrequest, web-crawler, wikipedia

I am new to `Web Crawling`, and I am using `HttpWebRequest` to crawl data from sites.

As of now I was successfully able to crawl and get data from my wordpress site. This data was a simple user profile data. (like name, email, AIM id etc...)

Now as an exercise I want to crawl wikipedia, where I will search using the value entered into textbox at my end and then crawl wikipedia with the search value and get the appropriate title(s) from the search.

Now I have the following doubts/difficulties.

- Firstly, is this even possible ? I have heard that wiki has robot.txt setup to block this. Though I have heard this only from a friend and hence not sure.
- I am using the same procedure I used earlier, but I am not getting the required results.

Thanks !

**Update :**
After some explanation and help from [@svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick), I tried the below code, but still not able to get any value (see last line of code, there I am expecting an html markup of the search result page)

```
string searchUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Wikipedia&title=Special%3ASearch";

var postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("search=" + model.Query);
postData.Append("&");
postData.Append("title" + "Special:Search");

byte[] data2 = Crawler.GetEncodedData(postData.ToString());

var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(searchUrl);

webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.UserAgent = "Crawling HW (http://yassershaikh.com/contact-me/)";
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
requestStream.Close();

var responseCsv = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream response = responseCsv.GetResponseStream();

// Todo Parsing
var streamReader = new StreamReader(response);
string val = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

// val is empty !! <-- this is my problem !
```

and here is my `GetEncodedData` method defination.

```
public static byte[] GetEncodedData(string postData)
    {
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        return data;
    }
```

Pls help me on this.

Comment: If you have some sort of problem, you really should tell us what *exactly* the problem is. Saying that you're “not getting the required results” doesn't tell us much. What *do* you get?

Comment: i am getting an empty web response. I was seeing  wiki's robot.txt file, I dont have much idea on what it does but it said it disallowed ` Disallow: /wiki/Special:Search` which I am using to search... I am new to crawling and hence dont know what hakf of these means... pls help

Comment: Have you tried monitoring what goes "over the wire" with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You probably don't need to use `HttpWebRequest`. Using `WebClient` (or `HttpClient` if you're on .Net 4.5) will be much easier for you.
2. [`robots.txt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) doesn't actually block anything. If something doesn't support it (and .Net doesn't support it), it can access anything.
3. Wikipedia does block requests that don't have their [`User-Agent` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) set. [And you should use an informative User-Agent string with your contact information.](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy)
4. A better way to access Wikipedia is to use [its API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), rather than scraping. This way, you will get an answer that's specifically meant to be read by a custom applications, formatted as XML or JSON. [There are also dumps containing all information from Wikipedia available for download.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download)

**EDIT:** The problem with your newly posted code is that your query returns a [302 Moved Temporarily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response to the searched article, if it exists. Either remove the line that forbids `AllowAutoRedirect`, or add `&fulltext=Search` to your query, which will mean you won't get redirected.

Comment: ok... now m this is starting to make sense to me. Thanks ! but is it possible to srcape data from wikipedia using .net... this is more like a homework on crawling and nt a real world app or something.

Comment: I guess I didn't say that clearly: Yes, you can scrape Wikipedia, you just need to set the User-Agent. But the API is preferred for any serious work.

Comment: Ok, thanks with all this information in hand, now I'm gonna try again. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I have added the code I am using but still not able to get the required result, pls help me further on this. thanks